# GitHub: Require specific checks to pass before merging

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I was reading about RuleSets and I want to implement [require status checks to pass before merging](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets). I want to implement the following workflow:

- job1: Check whether a PR has approval from a specific GitHub group. It is only relevant to changes in a specific file path.
- job2: Depending on the success of job1, push changes to another repo having the same file path.

If I add this check in the repository settings and enable "Require status checks to pass before merging", it would mean that other PRs not having any changes to the file path would be blocked from merging if the checks fails. How should I make sure that other PRs are not blocked from merging?

It seems that workflows [skipped](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets) due to path filtering are marked as pending and those PRs would be blocked from merging.

Is it recommended to use GitHub Actions like [changed-files](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files?ref=blog.pantsbuild.org) instead of using the `paths` filter at workflow level. I believe skipping a job would not mark the workflow as failed.

Comment: Basically, I was thinking to implement some action like changed-files as a step inside job1

Comment: For `job1`, you can use `CODEOWNERS` instead. For `job2`, you can have an event listener for `on.push.[master]` and run that job